# Creating reusable REST resource for Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

Let's say I have an entity called `Book` for a very simple RESTful app created within the Java Spring framework, i.e. I have the `Book` model/entity (which maps the data to/from the `books` table in a db). I have the `BookController` class which provides the following (rest api) endpoints:

- `GET /api/books` => `public ResponseEntity index()`
- `POST /api/books` => `public ResponseEntity store()`
- `GET /api/books/<id>` => `public ResponseEntity show(Long id)`
- `PATCH /api/books/<id>` => `public ResponseEntity update(Long id)`
- `DELETE /api/books/<id>` => `public ResponseEntity delete(Long id)`

Then there are the `BookService` and `BookRepository` classes implementing the service and persistance layers logic.

Is there some sort of a neat way to abstract this out in Java Spring, i.e. to create a bunch of annotations and a library/classes so that I could do something along the lines of

```java
@RestResource('book')
public class BookRestResource {
}
```

and all that (the controller, model, service, repository) would be created automatically (by Spring) for me?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spring Data Rest](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest):
Spring Data REST builds on top of Spring Data repositories, analyzes your application's domain model and exposes hypermedia-driven HTTP resources for aggregates contained in the model.

Basically you define your model and JPA repositories, and data rest handles the Controller, as a result you get the full CRUD operations exposed via HTTP (GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE).

Reference:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-intro